# Cython ownership manage memory

Tags: cython

I'm a little bit confused about the ownership,
Lets take this example: 
I initialize 2 object: obj1 and obj2 from a class BaseClass
and they point to some obj_ptr :

```
             obj1--->obj1_ptr
             obj2--->obj2_ptr
```

or let say they point to some memory area,where the data is created.
And I want to say to obj1: From now on i want you to take care of obj2
It will be something like :

```
       def getDependency(obj1):
             return[obj1_ptr,obj2_ptr]
```

So what will happen is this:

```
                obj1--->obj1_ptr---.
                                   |
                obj2--->obj2_ptr<--'
```

Once that the delete of obj1 is called it will go and delete obj2_ptr,obj1_ptr and itself
**Now the problem is on obj2 that will point to some where in the memory,and if it stays so
and is not destroy, it will create memory leak.**

**How can I manage the life time of an instance of the class giving the ownership?**

What I was thinking to do was to create a class OwnerShipBase where to put the ownership,
create a cache actually using a hashTable were to put the dependecies for every instance,
but the problem is if i have to many obj the table will be so big. Then when i want to delete 
go in the table see all the dependecies and delete them. And give an exception if someone
after the delete try to call obj2. Than the GC will take care of it once that it won't be used
any more.

One other idea was to use the weak reference but as you never know when GC is going to run
it can happen that it destroys your object before you can even use them.

Comment: Is obj_ptr is a C pointer or a Python object ?

Answer (score 0):

Make a wrapper object that is responsible for the c-allocated memory, and let your other objects use that wrapper for all access. It will keep your code clean, and let python runtime handle all the dependencies/refcounting/etc.

Something like:

```
obj1 --\
        => wrapper -> ptr
obj2 --/
```

If you want to free that memory while objects are still using it you can always free the underlying pointer in your wrapper object, then throw a python exception if something tries to access it afterwards.